# finding out difference between two times

Tags: php

I wrote the following code to determine the amount of time that employees spend on a task:

```
$time1 = $row_TicketRS['OpenTime'];
$time2= $row_TicketRS['CloseTime'];

$t1=strtotime($time1); 
$t2=strtotime($time2);


$end=strtotime(143000);  //143000 is reference to 14:30


//$Hours =floor((($t2 - $t1)/60)/60); 

$Hours = floor((($end- $t1)/60)/60);


echo   $Hours.' Hours ';
```

The above code is not giving me the correct time.

For example, with a start time of 09:19:00 and end time of 11:01:00 it give me duration time of only 1 hour which is wrong.  What is the correct way?

Comment: `143000 is refer to 14:30`?? what it means>

Comment: also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: `echo (new DateTime($time2))->diff(new DateTime($time1))->format('h');`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After changing `strtotime('14:30:00')`  everything working fine.. see below

```
$time1 = '09:19:00';
$time2= '11:01:00';

echo "Time1:".$t1=strtotime($time1); 
echo "<br/>Time2:".$t2=strtotime($time2);    

echo "<br/>End:".$end=strtotime('14:30:00'); 
echo  "<br/>Floor value:";  
var_dump(floor((($end- $t1)/60)/60));     

//$Hours =floor((($t2 - $t1)/60)/60); 

$Hours = floor((($end- $t1)/60)/60);    

echo   $Hours.' Hours ';
```

Answer (score 10):

Your use of `floor` is why you are getting only 1 hour for those inputs.  Those inputs result in 1.7 hours if you keep the answer as a float.  `floor` automatically rounds down to the lower integer value.  Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php for more info.

```
$t1 = strtotime('09:19:00');
$t2 = strtotime('11:01:00');
$hours = ($t2 - $t1)/3600;   //$hours = 1.7
```

If you want a more fine-grained time difference, you can flesh it out...

```
echo floor($hours) . ':' . ( ($hours-floor($hours)) * 60 );  // Outputs "1:42"
```

**UPDATE:**

I just noted your comments on Long Ears' answer.  Please check my comments above again, they are correct.  Inputting values of '09:11:00' and '09:33:00' results in 0 hours (22 minutes).

If you input those values and got 4 hours, you likely have a decimal error in your math. Using '09:11' to '09:33', the result is .367 hours.  If you divided the `strtotime` results by 360 instead of by 3600, you would get result 3.67 hours (or 4 hours, depending on your rounding method).

`strtotime` [converts your time to an `int` value](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) representing number of seconds since Unix epoch.  Since you convert both values to seconds, and then subtract the values from each other, the resulting value is a quantity of seconds.  There are 3600 seconds in 1 hour.

Comment: echo floor($hours) . ':' . floor( ($hours-floor($hours)) * 60 );  it should be like this else minutes will display in points sometimes

Answer (score 5):

```
function getTimeDiff($dtime,$atime)
{
    $nextDay=$dtime>$atime?1:0;
    $dep=explode(':',$dtime);
    $arr=explode(':',$atime);


    $diff=abs(mktime($dep[0],$dep[1],0,date('n'),date('j'),date('y'))-mktime($arr[0],$arr[1],0,date('n'),date('j')+$nextDay,date('y')));

    //Hour

    $hours=floor($diff/(60*60));

    //Minute 

    $mins=floor(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));

    //Second

    $secs=floor(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));

    if(strlen($hours)<2)
    {
        $hours="0".$hours;
    }

    if(strlen($mins)<2)
    {
        $mins="0".$mins;
    }

    if(strlen($secs)<2)
    {
        $secs="0".$secs;
    }

    return $hours.':'.$mins.':'.$secs;

}

echo getTimeDiff("23:30","01:30");
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$start_t = new DateTime($start_time);
$current_t = new DateTime($current_time);
$difference = $start_t ->diff($current_t );
$return_time = $difference ->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `strtotime('14:30')` rather than `strtotime(143000)`

**Edit:**  Actually to my surprise, `strtotime(143000)` does seem to have the desired effect but only for double-digit hours so I still wouldn't rely on it. Anyway it's not the cause of your problem ;)

Comment: thanks dear but do you have any idea my the duration is not correct

Comment: ok thanks for all who tried to help well now for some tasks the duration is correct but for some is still wrong like someont start his task at 09:11:00 and finish at 09:33:00 and it gives me 4 hr duration?!

Answer (score 0):

> for example the start time is 09:19:00 and end time is 11:01:00 but it give me duration time only 1 hour which is wrong

You are calculating the difference in hours. what is the correct result for "start time is 09:19:00 and end time is 11:01:00"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$hour = ($end - $t1)/(60*60)`

In this the time format is (seconds*minutes*days*months*years) => (60*60*2)

Comment: ok thanks for all who tried to help well now for some tasks the duration is correct but for some is still wrong like someont start his task at 09:11:00 and finish at 09:33:00 and it gives me 4 hr duration?!