# Calculating Time difference between two times in hh:mm format - PHP

Tags: php, time

I am trying to calculate the time difference in hours between to times in format hh:mm. The problem is the data is in both 12 hour and 24 hour. 
eg. 23:55 - 00:10 , 12:10 - 01:02, 10:50 - 11:10 etc..

I tried the method given here [PHP - hours difference (HH:MM format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351981/php-hours-difference-hhmm-format)

I need a function with all conditions to handle the 24h, 12h to calculate the time difference in hours.

Many thanks.

Comment: if it's 12 hours you should have an AM/PM parameter right?

Comment: You don't have any dates?

Comment: Create \DateTime objects for the times you want to compare and use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php to compare them

Answer (score 0):

The code in [linked solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10352078/2329487) is fine except over midnight case. If you assume positive difference (start before end) - you may add 1 day (in seconds) when it appears to be negative. Just change return statement to:

```
return ($timeDiff > 0) ? $timeDiff : $timeDiff + 24*60*60;
```