# Substracting multiple data type times in php

Tags: php

I need to subtract data time 2 times to get the final time, i got this "05:00"-"01:00"-"00:30".

`$time1 = new dateTime('05:00');
$time2 = new dateTime('01:00');
$time3 = new dateTime('00:30');
$result = $time1->diff($time2);`

and using this I could pull the difference from $time1 and $time2 but then i can't use ->diff again because it's dateInterval now.

Comment: Use public DateInterval::format ( string $format ) : string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding out difference between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177334/finding-out-difference-between-two-times)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to this can be using DateInterval instances directly with the DateTime::sub() method.

```
$time1 = new DateTime();
$time2 = new DateInterval('PT5H');
$time3 = new DateInterval('PT30M');

$result = $time1
    ->sub($time2)
    ->sub($time3)
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

var_dump($result); // 2020-04-23 04:24:24 (5 hours and 30 minutes earlier)
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [DateTime::diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) docs, it is defined as

`DateTime::diff ( DateTimeInterface $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = FALSE ] ) : DateInterval` and therefore returns of type `DateInterval`.

There are already other correct answers to achieve the subtraction in PHP:

[finding out difference between two times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177334/finding-out-difference-between-two-times)

Comment: As written above the questioner already knows how to find out the difference between two dates. His issue is how to subtract more than one time from another. So this answer is not helping.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$time1 = '05:00';
$time2 = '01:00';
$time3 = '00:30';

function str_to_minutes($str) {
    $arr = explode(':', $str);
    return (int)$arr[0] * 60 + (int)$arr[1];
}

function minutes_to_str($min) {
    echo sprintf("%02d:%02d", $min / 60, $min % 60);
}
echo minutes_to_str(str_to_minutes($time1) - str_to_minutes($time2) - str_to_minutes($time3));
//03:30
```